# Google Charts bar chart: How to manually change the colour of every bar? (single series)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have written a simple bar chart with Google Charts, one series, it works fine, all bars are blue:

[image: Google Charts bar]

Now I would like to **manually set the colour of the every single bar** (actually a green-to-red transition proportional to the value, to make it easier to understand what is good/bad).
How can I do this?

I have tried setting `colors` in `options` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878282/226958) but for some reason it does not work in my code below.

[chco](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/bar_charts#series_colors) seems to be what I need, but it is an URL parameter... how to elegantly integrate it in JavaScript code?

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Product', 'Score'],
          ['NemakiWare',  288],
          ['Nuxeo',  240],
          ['FileNet',  220],
          ['SharePoint',  98]
        ]);

        var options = {
            colors: ['green','blue','pink','red'],
            legend: 'none',
            hAxis: {
                textPosition: 'none',
                minValue: 0,
                gridlines: {
                    color: 'transparent'
                }
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to do this but you can use the style role.

**Source:**
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Colors

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Product', 'Score', { role: 'style' }],
          ['NemakiWare',  288, 'green'],
          ['Nuxeo',  240, 'blue'],
          ['FileNet',  220, 'pink'],
          ['SharePoint',  98, 'red']
        ]);

        var options = {
            legend: 'none',
            hAxis: {
                textPosition: 'none',
                minValue: 0,
                gridlines: {
                    color: 'transparent'
                }
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.clearChart();
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```