# how to set gradient color to column bar for google chart

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using google chart in android app. I have used column chart to display graph data. But I want to set gradient color to bar.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share the code that you are working on. And also describe what you have tried so far. You are more likely to get help that way.

Comment: I am using ColumnChart not Line Chart

Comment: Is your answer found here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592776/google-charts-change-individual-bar-color

Answer (score 0):

try this

Combining methods from multiple sources, I arrived at this solution for changing the background of the chart -

```
//Set background opacity and fill
d3.selectAll('.chart g.c3-event-rects').style('fill-opacity', '1');
d3.selectAll('.chart g.c3-event-rects').style('fill', 'url(#something)');

//Insert gradient

let gradient = d3.select('defs')
.append('linearGradient')
.attr('id', 'gradient')
.attr('x1', '50%').attr('y1', '0%')
.attr('x2', '50%').attr('y2', '100%');

gradient
  .append('stop')
  .attr('offset', '0%')
  .attr('stop-color', '#FFFFFF')
  .attr('stop-opacity', '1');

gradient
  .append('stop')
  .attr('offset', '100%')
  .attr('stop-color', '#B38EE8')
  .attr('stop-opacity', '0');
```

Comment: I want to change bar color not the graph background